# Python Tkinter scrollbar in multiple tabs

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, scrollbar, tk-toolkit

I learned how to make a scrollable frame by embedding the frame in a canvas and then adding a scrollbar to it like this:

```
def __add_widget_features(self, feat_tab):
    table_frame = ttk.Frame(feat_tab)
    table_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
    self.__make_grid(table_frame)

    ####subframe####              
    self.canvas = Canvas(table_frame, borderwidth=0, background="#ffffff")
    self.frame = LabelFrame(self.canvas, background="#ffffff", text="Timetable")
    self.vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(table_frame, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas.yview)
    self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)

    self.vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
    self.canvas.pack(side="right", fill="both", expand=True)
    self.canvas.create_window((4,4), window=self.frame, anchor="nw", 
                              tags="self.frame")

    self.frame.bind("<Configure>", self.OnFrameConfigure)
```

My program has a gui that creates multiple tabs. The scrollable canvas works great in one tab, but when I try to add the same code to a second a tab, the scrollbar doesn't work on that tab.  If I comment out the code block on the first tab, it works fine on the other one.  I've already tried naming all of the elements of the second tab something different (in case that was the problem) and I've tried taking out the "self." part of the names but none of that helped.  I'm quite new to Python so I'm sure I'm missing something simple. I tried posting a picture of the problem but my rep isn't high enough yet.  Any help would be great.

**UPDATE:** per Brionius's suggestion, here's the function for creating the notebook:

```
def __add_widget_datawindow(self):
    '''(FordTIPGui) -> NoneType
    Populate the data_window with widgets.
    '''

    # add data_window frame
    data_frame = ttk.Frame(self.data_window)
    data_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
    self.__make_grid(data_frame)
    self.add_menubar(self.data_window, "other") # add menubar

    # add subframes and make them into a grid
    button_frame = ttk.Frame(data_frame)
    button_frame.grid(row=9, column=0, rowspan=1, columnspan=10,sticky=W+E+N+S)
    self.__make_grid(button_frame)
    nb_frame = ttk.Frame(data_frame)
    nb_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=9, columnspan=10, sticky=W+E+N+S)

    ## add widgets to subframes ##

    # button_frame
    disc_button = ttk.Button(button_frame, text="Disconnect", command=lambda:self.disconnect())
    disc_button.grid(row=10, column=0, columnspan=1, sticky=W+E+N+S)

    # nb_frame
    nb = ttk.Notebook(nb_frame) # create notebook
    nb.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

    # create frames for tabs
    tab_frame1 = ttk.Frame(nb)
    tab_frame2 = ttk.Frame(nb)
    tab_frame3 = ttk.Frame(nb)
    tab_frame4 = ttk.Frame(nb)
    tab_frame5 = ttk.Frame(nb)
    self.__make_grid(tab_frame1)
    self.__make_grid(tab_frame2)
    self.__make_grid(tab_frame3)
    self.__make_grid(tab_frame4)
    self.__make_grid(tab_frame5)

    # add tabs
    nb.add(tab_frame1, text='Confidential1 View')
    nb.add(tab_frame2, text='Confidential2 View')
    nb.add(tab_frame3, text='Confidential3 View')
    nb.add(tab_frame4, text='Confidential4 View')
    nb.add(tab_frame5, text='Confidential5 View')

    # add widgets
    self.__add_widget_group(tab_frame1)
    self.__add_widget_feature(tab_frame2)
    self.__add_widget_signal(tab_frame3)
    self.__add_widget_features(tab_frame4)
    self.__add_widget_timetable(tab_frame5)
```

pic of the problem: http://www.use.com/supersize.pl?set=3059c6e412c1416578a7

Comment: Since you say the problem is related to multiple tabs in (what I assume is) a ttk Notebook, you're probably going to have to show us the code that involves the multiple tabs; I don't see anything obviously wrong with the code here.  Also, re: posting the image, you can also use something like [tinypic](http://tinypic.com/) and post a link.

Comment: Ok, from the picture, I'm guessing the problem you're referring to is that the scrollbar on the second frame looks inactive/grayed out?  Where is the first bunch of code called in the second bunch of code?  Is the first bunch of code inside the function `__make_grid`?  Still pretty hard to put together what's going on based on the snippets you've posted.

Comment: Sorry, the first block of code is called in self.__add_widget_features(tab_frame4) and
self.__add_widget_timetable(tab_frame5).  It works in frame_5 but not in frame_4.  If I comment out the first block of code in frame_5, then the scrollbar in frame_4 is active

Comment: what does `__make_grid` do?

Comment: it configures a 10x10 grid by default.  I got this code from a co-worker's previous project and started hacking it up to serve my needs so I'm just following her way of creating the grids.  I originally though that __make_grid was a tk function so I'm not exactly sure why the grids are being instantiated that way, but it seems to work fine.  I have had no problem adding widgets to the grid to make it way larger than 10x10 (try 39x203)

Comment: Are you defining `self.canvas` and `self.vsb` in more than one place in your code?

Comment: yes, I define them in add_widget_features and in add_widget_timetable.  I thought that that would be the problem, so I tried changing them to self.canvas1 and self.vsb1 but had no luck

Comment: For the frame-in-a-canvas trick to work, you also need to set the `scrollregion` attribute. Are you doing that anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably doing something wrong with the parent/child relationships. Look at this code:

```
def __add_widget_timetable(self, timetable_tab):
    table_frame = ttk.Frame(feat_tab)
    table_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
    self.__make_grid(table_frame)
```

Notice how you're passing in a frame (`timetable_tab`), creating another tab (`table_frame`), and putting that created frame in some other frame (`feat_tab`).

Something seems rather wrong. My guess is that `table_frame` should be a child of `timetable_tab`.

Comment: That was a paste error.  I do have the table_frame as a child of feat_tab in the feature tab and then another table_frame in my timetable function that is a child of the timetable_tab

Comment: @user979489: if you want us to help solve problems, you need to post the actual code that solves problems. How are we to know which bugs are copy/paste errors and which are the real problem?

Comment: Sorry about that. I copied my code and pasted it, but missed that top line and then copied it from the wrong part of my code.  Just a mistake...  I corrected it in the question.  The code in the question is my actual code that I am having trouble with.