# Using Scrollbar in multiple tabs Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

I've created a multipage program (using Python 2.7 and Tkinter on a Mac), with navigation buttons between the pages. I want to be able to use Scrollbar on some of the pages, but when I put in the Scrollbar code for each page, only the last page with the scrollbar code added is scrollable. The scrollbar works great (I understand how to make it), but it seems that only one page can have a working scrollbar at a time. Why? This exact question (almost) was asked several years ago here ([Python Tkinter scrollbar in multiple tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18254813/python-tkinter-scrollbar-in-multiple-tabs)) but was never answered. I've also tried putting the scrollbar code into the "main window" and the "create new file" class code, but funky things happen. Here's a basic version of what I'm trying to do:

```
from Tkinter import *

def quit(): #quits the program
    master.destroy()

class FirstPage(Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        #creating vertical and horizontal scrollbars
        self.canvas = Canvas(self, background = "#ffffff", 
            highlightcolor = "white")
        self.canvas.pack(side = "left", fill = "both", anchor = "center",
            expand = True)

        self.vscrollbar = Scrollbar(self, orient = "vertical", 
            command = self.canvas.yview)
        self.vscrollbar.pack(side = "right", fill = "y")
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand = self.vscrollbar.set)

        self.hscrollbar = Scrollbar(self, orient = "horizontal", 
            command = self.canvas.xview)
        self.hscrollbar.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "x")
        self.canvas.configure(xscrollcommand = self.hscrollbar.set)

        self.container = Frame(self.canvas, highlightcolor = "white")

        self.canvas.create_window(0, 0, window = self.container, 
            anchor = "center")

        self.container.bind("<Configure>", self.onFrameConfigure)
        self.canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", self.on_vertical)
        self.canvas.bind_all("<Shift-MouseWheel>", self.on_horizontal)


        self.label = Label(self.container, text = "Welcome!")
        self.label.pack(side = "top", fill = "both", expand = False)

    def onFrameConfigure(self, event):
        #Reset the scroll region to encompass the inner frame
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion = self.canvas.bbox("all"))

    def on_vertical(self, event):
        self.canvas.yview_scroll(-1 * event.delta, 'units')
        #lets the user use the mouse/trackpad to vertically scroll

    def on_horizontal(self, event):
        self.canvas.xview_scroll(-1 * event.delta, 'units')
        #lets the user use the shift-mouse/trackpad to horizontally scroll

class SecondPage(Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        #creating vertical and horizontal scrollbars
        self.canvas = Canvas(self, background = "#ffffff", 
            highlightcolor = "white")
        self.canvas.pack(side = "left", fill = "both", anchor = "center",
            expand = True)

        self.vscrollbar = Scrollbar(self, orient = "vertical", 
            command = self.canvas.yview)
        self.vscrollbar.pack(side = "right", fill = "y")
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand = self.vscrollbar.set)

        self.hscrollbar = Scrollbar(self, orient = "horizontal", 
            command = self.canvas.xview)
        self.hscrollbar.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "x")
        self.canvas.configure(xscrollcommand = self.hscrollbar.set)

        self.container = Frame(self.canvas, highlightcolor = "white")

        self.canvas.create_window(0, 0, window = self.container, 
            anchor = "center")

        self.container.bind("<Configure>", self.onFrameConfigure)
        self.canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", self.on_vertical)
        self.canvas.bind_all("<Shift-MouseWheel>", self.on_horizontal)


        self.label = Label(self.container, text = "Hello World!")
        self.label.pack(side = "top", fill = "both", expand = False)

    def onFrameConfigure(self, event):
        #Reset the scroll region to encompass the inner frame
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion = self.canvas.bbox("all"))

    def on_vertical(self, event):
        self.canvas.yview_scroll(-1 * event.delta, 'units')
        #lets the user use the mouse/trackpad to vertically scroll

    def on_horizontal(self, event):
        self.canvas.xview_scroll(-1 * event.delta, 'units')
        #lets the user use the shift-mouse/trackpad to horizontally scroll


class ThirdPage(Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        #creating vertical and horizontal scrollbars
        self.canvas = Canvas(self, background = "#ffffff", 
            highlightcolor = "white")
        self.canvas.pack(side = "left", fill = "both", anchor = "center",
            expand = True)

        self.vscrollbar = Scrollbar(self, orient = "vertical", 
            command = self.canvas.yview)
        self.vscrollbar.pack(side = "right", fill = "y")
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand = self.vscrollbar.set)

        self.hscrollbar = Scrollbar(self, orient = "horizontal", 
            command = self.canvas.xview)
        self.hscrollbar.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "x")
        self.canvas.configure(xscrollcommand = self.hscrollbar.set)

        self.container = Frame(self.canvas, highlightcolor = "white")

        self.canvas.create_window(0, 0, window = self.container, 
            anchor = "center")

        self.container.bind("<Configure>", self.onFrameConfigure)
        self.canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", self.on_vertical)
        self.canvas.bind_all("<Shift-MouseWheel>", self.on_horizontal)


        self.label = Label(self.container, text = "Hello World 2.0!")
        self.label.pack(side = "top", fill = "both", expand = False)

    def onFrameConfigure(self, event):
        #Reset the scroll region to encompass the inner frame
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion = self.canvas.bbox("all"))

    def on_vertical(self, event):
        self.canvas.yview_scroll(-1 * event.delta, 'units')
        #lets the user use the mouse/trackpad to vertically scroll

    def on_horizontal(self, event):
        self.canvas.xview_scroll(-1 * event.delta, 'units')
        #lets the user use the shift-mouse/trackpad to horizontally scroll


class CreateNewFile(Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    """ If the scrollbar code goes here (and container is deleted then 
        replaced with self.container), then the buttonframe gets pushed to 
        the bottom, and the two buttons do not work (I cannot see the 
        pages they create). The scrollbar also doesn't work.
    """

        #the pages the buttons will navigate to
        secondpage = SecondPage(self)
        thirdpage = ThirdPage(self)

        #creating the navigation bar vs. the window
        buttonframe = Frame(self)
        buttonframe.pack(side = "top", fill = "x", anchor = "w", expand = 
            False)

        #creating the window container
        container = Frame(self)
        container.pack(side = "top", fill = "both", expand = True)

        #placing the pages in the container
        secondpage.place(in_ = container, x = 0, y = 0, relwidth = 1,
            relheight = 1)
        thirdpage.place(in_ = container, x = 0, y = 0, relwidth = 1,
            relheight = 1)

        #placing the buttons in the navigation bar
        secondpagebutton = Button(buttonframe, text = "2nd Page", command =         
            secondpage.lift)
        secondpagebutton.pack(side = "left") 

        thirdpagebutton = Button(buttonframe, text = "3rd Page", command = 
            thirdpage.lift)
        thirdpagebutton.pack(side = "left") 



class MainWindow(Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        #the pages the buttons will nagivate to
        firstpage = FirstPage(self)
        createnewfile = CreateNewFile(self)

    """ If the scrollbar code goes here (and container is deleted then 
        replaced with self.container), then the buttonframe gets pushed to 
        the bottom, and the the createnewfilebutton does not work (I 
        cannot see the page it creates). The scrollbar also doesn't work.
    """

        #creating the button navigation bar and the rest of the window so the 
        #buttons are always visible no matter which page you're on
        buttonframe = Frame(self)
        buttonframe.pack(side = "top", fill = "x", expand = False)

        #creating the window container
        container = Frame(self)
        container.pack(side = "top", fill = "both", expand = True)

        #placing the pages in the container
        firstpage.place(in_ = container, x = 0, y = 0, relwidth = 1,
            relheight = 1)
        createnewfile.place(in_ = container, x = 0, y = 0, relwidth = 1,
            relheight = 1)

        #placing the buttons in the navigation bar
        quitbutton = Button(buttonframe, text = "Quit", command = quit)
        quitbutton.pack(side = "left") #this quits the whole program 

        createnewfilebutton = Button(buttonframe, text = "Create New File",
            command = createnewfile.lift)
        createnewfilebutton.pack(side = "left")

        firstpage.lift()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    master = Tk()
    main = MainWindow(master)
    main.pack(side = "top", fill = "both", expand = True)
    main.master.title("Basic Example")
    master.wm_geometry("600x500+0+0")
    master.mainloop()
```

Is there a way to have each page scroll, or do I need to give up on being able to scroll through multiple widgets on each page and just have scrolling on the widgets that support it (like the text widget)?

Comment: Your code only has one scrollbar and only one page. Please include a [mcve].

Comment: Does it not have multiple pages? Perhaps "tab" would have been a better word. I'll add the scrollbar code back in to the three pages.

Comment: I apologize. I was looking at the code on an ipad and didn’t see that more code was scrolled out of view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `self.canvas.bind_all` creates a global binding. You first bind `<MouseWheel>` to the first canvas. Then, you override that binding and bind it to the second. Then, you override that binding and bind it to the third.

You either need to change the global binding each time you change the page, or add the binding to each canvas directly with `bind` rather than `bind_all`. Your third choice is to make your binding smart enough to scroll whichever canvas is visible.

Comment: That was it, thank you! (Tried to upvote, but don't have enough reputation for it to be publicly visible) +1